# arcgis.learn show_batch() index error and lr_find() runtime error while using pointcnn for LiDAR segmentation

Tags: python, arcgis-pro, lidar, point-cloud, arcgis-python-api

I am trying to segment vegetation from LiDAR point cloud using PointCNN on Jupyter notebook. But I am getting Index Error on running show_batch()  and runtime error on running lr_find() while using arcgis.learn (ArcGIS Python API)

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-15-0ef5bf68f37d> in <module>
----> 1 data.show_batch(rows=10)

~\AppData\Local\ESRI\conda\envs\my_arcgispro-py3\lib\site-packages\arcgis\learn\_utils\pointcloud_data.py in show_point_cloud_batch_TF(self, rows, color_mapping, **kwargs)
292             mask = x > -9999999
293 
--> 294         color_list =  color_mapping[labels[sample_idxs]][mask].tolist()
295 
296         scene=dict(aspectmode='data')

IndexError: index 5 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 4
```

and on running

```
pcnn = PointCNN(data)
pcnn.lr_find()


RuntimeError: Assertion `cur_target >= 0 && cur_target < n_classes' failed.  at ..\aten\src\THNN/generic/ClassNLLCriterion.c:92
```

Any pointers that can help me in solving/debugging these error?

full code
[image]
[image]
[image]

I am open to suggestions regarding any other method of LiDAR segmentation.

Comment: Coding questions should contain code, not pictures of code. Pictures are not searchable or even legible on all devices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

okay so I solved it. My training LIDAR was classified as
[image]

So instead I reclassified it to (ignore the string class):

[image: I also removed class 7 which was originally low noise hence now I had total 5 classes]

Now the values were continuous and the missing class values "1" and "4" (as in line[7] of question above) which were causing index error and runtime error seems to be resolved. The lr_find() is still running (which is possibly good news). I'll update when it's completed.